# What does the with statement in this code co calculate ordinal logistic regression do?

Tags: r

I am reading the https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/. There is a part of codes that I could not understand.

In the following codes, what is the role of `with(dat, summary(as.numeric(apply) ~ pared + public + gpa, fun=sf))`? I know qlogis(), but I could not understand what did this combination do.

```
dat <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta")
m <- polr(apply ~ pared + public + gpa, data = dat, Hess=TRUE)
summary(m)
sf <- function(y) {
    c('Y>=1' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)),
      'Y>=2' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)),
      'Y>=3' = qlogis(mean(y >= 3)))
}
with(dat, summary(as.numeric(apply) ~ pared + public + gpa, fun=sf))
```

This is the results.

```
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
|       |           |  N|Y>=1|        Y>=2|      Y>=3|
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
|  pared|         No|337| Inf|-0.378336441|-2.4407354|
|       |        Yes| 63| Inf| 0.765467842|-1.3470736|
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
| public|         No|343| Inf|-0.204794413|-2.3450058|
|       |        Yes| 57| Inf|-0.175890666|-1.5475625|
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
|    gpa|[1.90,2.73)|102| Inf|-0.397301797|-2.7725887|
|       |[2.73,3.00)| 99| Inf|-0.264151575|-2.3025851|
|       |[3.00,3.28)|100| Inf|-0.200670695|-2.0907411|
|       |[3.28,4.00]| 99| Inf| 0.060624622|-1.8035939|
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
|Overall|           |400| Inf|-0.200670695|-2.1972246|
+-------+-----------+---+----+------------+----------+
```

What is the meaning of "-0.378336441" and "2.4407354" in the first line?
Anybody could give me a simple code to get these values?

Answer (score 2):

The `with` command evaluates the expression taking the dat variable as the local environment. This is used mostly to avoid repeatedly use of `dat$var1, dat$var2..` in an expression.  For example, if you want to compute the mean of 3 variables of dataframe dat instead of using

```
dat$mean<-(dat$var1+dat$var2+dat$var3)/3
```

(a lot of `dat$`!) you can use

```
with(dat,mean<-(var1+var2+va3)/3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also please explain the meaning of `as.numeric(apply) ~ pared + public + gpa`? It appears to be a linear regression formula similar to lm(). I am unsure about what information can be obtained from this formula.